# need to disable fadeout function for the dropdown (only) menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with my menu in mobile mode. onClick it fadesOut. I want to keep this setting, but I don't want it to fadeOut when one clicks on the dropdown part.
here is link: http://jsfiddle.net/zLLzrs6b/3/ 
appreciate your help!

**html:**

```
<nav id="nav-wrap"> <a class="mobile-btn" href="#nav-wrap" title="Show navigation">Show Menu</a>
 <a class="mobile-btn" href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide Menu</a> 
    <ul id="nav" class="nav">
        <li><a class="smoothscroll mobile" href="#about">about</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="smoothscroll mobile" href="#documents">blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">dropdown</a> 
            <ul class="langop">
                <li><a href="#">otion 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">otion 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**css:**

```
.langop {
    display:none;
    position: relative;
    width:auto;
}
.nav-item:hover .langop {
    display: block;
}
```

**java:**

```
var toggle_button = $("<a>", {
    id: "toggle-btn",
    html: "Menu",
    title: "Menu",
    href: "#"
});
var nav_wrap = $('nav#nav-wrap')
var nav = $("ul#nav");


nav_wrap.find('a.mobile-btn').remove();
nav_wrap.prepend(toggle_button);

toggle_button.on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    nav.slideToggle("fast");
});

if (toggle_button.is(':visible')) nav.addClass('mobile');
$(window).resize(function () {
    if (toggle_button.is(':visible')) nav.addClass('mobile');
    else nav.removeClass('mobile');
});

$('ul#nav li a').on("click", function () {
    if (nav.hasClass('mobile')) nav.fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/zLLzrs6b/4/).

```
$('ul#nav > li > a').on("click", function () {
    if (nav.hasClass('mobile')) 
        nav.fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the clicked element by using **[`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)**, if it's dropdown part then don't  hide

```js
var toggle_button = $("<a>", {
  id: "toggle-btn",
  html: "Menu",
  title: "Menu",
  href: "#"
});
var nav_wrap = $('nav#nav-wrap')
var nav = $("ul#nav");


nav_wrap.find('a.mobile-btn').remove();
nav_wrap.prepend(toggle_button);

toggle_button.on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  nav.slideToggle("fast");
});

if (toggle_button.is(':visible')) nav.addClass('mobile');
$(window).resize(function() {
  if (toggle_button.is(':visible')) nav.addClass('mobile');
  else nav.removeClass('mobile');
});
$('ul#nav li a').on("click", function(e) {
  var target = $(".langop");
  if (!target.is(e.target) //checking clicked item is the dripdown list
    && target.has(e.target).length === 0 //chekking clicked element is inside the dropdown
    && nav.hasClass('mobile')) {
    nav.fadeOut('fast');
  }
});
```

```css
.langop {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
}
.nav-item:hover .langop {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav-wrap">
  <a class="mobile-btn" href="#nav-wrap" title="Show navigation">Show Menu</a>

  <a class="mobile-btn" href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide Menu</a> 
  <ul id="nav" class="nav">
    <li><a class="smoothscroll mobile" href="#about">about</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll mobile" href="#documents">blog</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">dropdown</a> 
      <ul class="langop">
        <li><a href="#">otion 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">otion 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried:

$('ul#nav li a').on("click", function(e) {
  var target = $(".langop");
  if (!target.is(".langop")//checking clicked item is the dripdown list
    
     )
    if (nav.hasClass('mobile')) nav.fadeOut('fast');
});

but now, the menu doesn't fadeOut no matter what like i click

Comment: `var target = $(".langop");  
 if (!target.is(e.target) && target.has(e.target).length === 0 && nav.hasClass('mobile'))  nav.fadeOut('fast'); `

Comment: got it, i just wasn't clear before, changed the class to .nav-item and got what i wanted, thanks